# C++ howto use the same function twice with different name and different names for variables

Tags: c++, class, templates, function, variables

I have a function that commands a device. This device is available twice so I need the same functionality for two devices. Out of maintenance reasons I don't want to have to code the function twice (one for each device) because then I always need to apply changes twice.

The functions are the same in principle but are supposed to work on different variables. Is it possible to instantiate this function with kind of a "varying" name, similar to template but not with classes but names?
I try to provide an example. It should look something like this.

```
void function_x (int Var, double Vary, ...) {
int var3_x = getFunctionFromDatabase(var3_x);
double var2_x = getFunctionFromDatabase(var2_x);
// some operations
}
```

The functions are applied by two instances of a Device Handler class.
The variables var1_x, var2_x and var3_x are stored in a data pool as var1_1, var1_2, var2_1, ... the "same" variable but one for each device. One Controller commands the two devices via these variables and the data pool.

Is this possible somehow?

I hope that the problem got clear ;). This is my first question here :P.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possibly you need function pointers.

Comment: This sounds like you would be much better of using classes to encapsulate your (member) variables var1, var2, etc. It will also help to avoid code reuse. Is there any reason you are against using classes?

Comment: I still don't get why you can't just call function_x(var1,var2,var3) and then the same on three other variables?

Comment: - I think function pointers are not helpful because the two function do not exist as two...they are only supposed to be initiated as two different functions at runtime.
- Using classes seems like an overshoot but I will give it a thought. It's just that these functions are very primitive
- I cannot call the function on different variables because inside the function there are variables that are initiated through a data base. And i cannot provide them to the function as parameters...

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an array?  E.g.

```
var1[0], var1[1], etc.
```

Use an array element for each device that you manage.

You could do some trickery with macros, but I think the code will be more clear if you use arrays.

Even if the variables are in a library that you can't change, you could set up arrays of pointers to the original variables in an initialization function.  E.g.:

```
var1[0] = &var1_0;
var1[1] = &var1_1;
```

Then, function_x becomes function and would accept a parameter for the device index.

Comment: Arrays don't help because the variables are of different types.
Also the variables have fixed names in the central data base.
They have the same name but different instance for both devices
For example:  
  var3_x = getvarFromDatabase(hereIsTheNameOfTheVarInDatabase_x)  
  
  var3_1 = getvarFromDatabase(hereIsTheNameOfTheVarInDatabase_1)  
  var3_2 = getvarFromDatabase(hereIsTheNameOfTheVarInDatabase_2)

Answer (score 0):

You say they have different variables, in which case it would be a simple case of overloading the function. Your example implies that you want to get the function from a database in which case you would need to use function pointers. Another option is that you have 1 function and you pass a handle (or some such) to it (as well as your arguments) to identify which device it is.

Comment: In both cases the function receives the same (kind of) parameters, so overloading does not solve the problem.
What do you mean by handle?
I don't want to get the function from a database, but I want to declare a variable that gets its content from the database. The names of the variables in the database are already fixed like value0_1, value0_2, value1_1, value1_2, each variable for each of the devices, so every variable in the datapool has two instances. I have to provide these names to the get function, that's why they also contain the "x".

Comment: Would a macro suffice then? That won't care about types and will have 1 implementation. e.g.
`#define FUNC(X,Y,Z) X = Y; Z = X/2; `
X,Y,Z could be any number type in this instance.